# displayind contents in list view

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Ihave an xml file  sample.xml

i need to display number  from above xml file in a listview named _listView which
contain version column named _version,can you give me the optimized code required to do
that task

Comment: can you show us your unoptimized code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://tempuri.org/SpoDataSchema.xsd";
string version = (string)XDocument.Load("sample.xml").Root
     .Element(ns + "ManagedObject").Element(ns + "version");
```

Or in 2.0:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("sample.xml");
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("spo", "http://tempuri.org/SpoDataSchema.xsd");
XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode(
    "/spo:SpoDataSchema/spo:ManagedObject/spo:version", nsmgr);
string version = node == null ? null : node.InnerText;
```

Then display `version` however you want. For displaying in a `ListView`:

```
using (Form form = new Form())
using (ListView lv = new ListView())
{
    lv.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    lv.View = View.Details;
    lv.Columns.Add("Version");
    lv.Items.Add(version);
    form.Controls.Add(lv);
    form.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: regarding XNamespace namespace its giving error assembly refernce or something

Comment: You will need .NET 3.5 and System.Xml.Linq.dll; if you are in 2.0/3.0 I can provide a 2.0-friendly version.

Comment: yes i need a complete coding to view it in listview as per the question what i gave in 2.0 version

Comment: but i am not able to see anything in listview

Comment: That is just a namespace; it doesn't get used. The `ListView` code works as presented; if it doesn't show for you, you're going to have to indicate what you are doing differently.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Xml.Linq;


string xml = ...
string version = XElement.Parse(xml).Element("ManagedObject").Attribute("version").Value;
```

There is an example on using a listview [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.aspx)

Comment: can you complete it up to displaying in to listview regarding the question

Comment: i am using version2.0 ,,i need a complete coding to view it in listview as per the question what i gave in 2.0 version though i am a beginner